# Mindmap diagram in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, mindmaps

What is the proper way to include a mindmap in Beamer like the following one (adapted from here http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/)?

Should insert with `includegraphics` the resulting object?

Also, which colors should I choose in order to better fit the standards of a presentation?

```
% Author: Till Tantau
% Source: The PGF/TikZ manual
\documentclass[french]{standalone}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=blue,text=white]
    node[concept] {Polyvalence}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Divers}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {Analyse dimension\-nelle} }
      child { node[concept] {Électricité} }
      child { node[concept] {Métho\-dologie} }
      child { node[concept] {Outils numériques} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Mécanique}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {Solide indéfor\-mable} }
       child { node[concept] {Milieux continus} }
      child { node[concept] {Point matériel} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {Thermo.} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {TP Physique} }
    child[concept color=red!40!black] {
      node[concept] {Lpro}
      [clockwise from=145]
      child { node[concept] {Machines thermiques} }
      child { node[concept] {Risques physiques} }
    }
    child[concept color=pink!80!black] {
      node[concept] {Unité enseignement ouverture}
      [clockwise from=45]
      child { node[concept] {Machines thermiques} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** (Into `beamer`)

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Enseignements}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=blue,text=white]
    node[concept] {Polyvalence}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Divers}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {Analyse dimension\-nelle} }
      child { node[concept] {Électricité} }
      child { node[concept] {Métho\-dologie} }
      child { node[concept] {Outils numériques} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Mécanique}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {Solide indéfor\-mable} }
       child { node[concept] {Milieux continus} }
      child { node[concept] {Point matériel} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {Thermo.} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {TP Physique} }
    child[concept color=red!40!black] {
      node[concept] {Lpro}
      [clockwise from=145]
      child { node[concept] {Machines thermiques} }
      child { node[concept] {Risques physiques} }
    }
    child[concept color=pink!80!black] {
      node[concept] {Unité enseignement ouverture}
      [clockwise from=45]
      child { node[concept] {Machines thermiques} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far (apart from the code, which is not yours)?

Comment: I personally would include the TeX code. This automatically gives you the same fonts as in the ambient document and also allows you to play with, say, `beamer-overlay-styles`.

Comment: @marmot Scaling the tikz path caused much amusement for this idiot \front{PTO} \back{PTO} is there a single point where the scaling is whole picture or  is a new \enclosure[scale=##]{required} ?

Comment: @JouleV I didn't pretend that the code is mine. I gave both the link and author's name.

Comment: @KJO I cannot achive proper scaling to fit into a slide.

Comment: Just replace `\begin{tikzpicture}` by `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45,transform shape]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `scale` option. In this case, `scale=0.5` is okay in my opinion. However, big text will mess up your picture, so I added option `transform shape` so that the text is also scaled.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Enseignements}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=blue,text=white]
    node[concept] {Polyvalence}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Divers}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {Analyse dimension\-nelle} }
      child { node[concept] {Électricité} }
      child { node[concept] {Métho\-dologie} }
      child { node[concept] {Outils numériques} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Mécanique}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {Solide indéfor\-mable} }
       child { node[concept] {Milieux continus} }
      child { node[concept] {Point matériel} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {Thermo.} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {TP Physique} }
    child[concept color=red!40!black] {
      node[concept] {Lpro}
      [clockwise from=145]
      child { node[concept] {Machines thermiques} }
      child { node[concept] {Risques physiques} }
    }
    child[concept color=pink!80!black] {
      node[concept] {Unité enseignement ouverture}
      [clockwise from=45]
      child { node[concept] {Machines thermiques} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, take care! The size of the text may be a bit small for presentations.

As for the color recommendation, I have no idea. I think even this color is good enough.